# Free voip server sending PJSIP_INV_STATE_DISCONNECTED to both the devices while call transfer causing call drop

Tags: iphone, ios4, sip, pjsip, sip-server

We have developed a VOIP client in iphone. Initally we tested it on Asterisk server and call transfer was working fine there.

Now we are using a free SIP server for testing. Now the problem is that when i am doing call transfer through this server, it's sending message PJSIP_INV_STATE_DISCONNECTED to both the end, it should send this message only to that party who are transferring the call. Because of that other end dismissing it's screen.

The problem is that this is the general event for call disconnect, so other end thinks that calling party has disconnected so it also disconnects.

anybody has ever faced such type of issue? Please give me some suggestion.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to answer my own question. Actually this is the normal SIP behavior. I interpret it in wrong way. Thanks